# NSPredicate a relationship objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7

i'm working with core data and i've two tables
List
ListItems

ListItems has a relationship named "parentlist" with destination set to "List"

I'm trying to query the ListItems for all the listItems whoes parent is X (List object)

i've tried this approach but it's not working

```
List* myList; // Initialized form other views
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"List == %@",myList]];
```

Comment: Is this in core data? or are the lists in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an inverse relationship `listItems` (as Apple recommends) you can use just:

```
myList.listItems
```

Comment: i've ended up using this approach. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code: In the predicate you have to use the relationship ("parentList"),
not the target entity ("List"). And you should not mix string formatting with
predicate formatting.

To get all ListItems related to the given list, the predicate would be

```
List* myList = ...; 
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"parentList == %@", myList];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're looking for something other than simply accessing the listItems through the list? If so :
comparing objects in core data doesn't really work that way. 
You could do this in one of two ways,
Easy   :  Assign the lists a GUID on creation using :

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString]
```

and use this for comparing two lists.

Harder :  implement a comparison function on the objects by overriding compare and compare the objects in a way that makes sense to you.

```
- (NSComparisonResult) compare : (List *) other;
```

Then create a NSPredicate using blocks.

You could also use a GUID and use it in the compare function, thus allowing you to expand on this later.